# Scrape Multiple articles from one page with each article with separate href

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am new to scrapy and writing my first spider make a scrapy spider for website similar to https://blogs.webmd.com/diabetes/default.htm

I want to scrape Headlines and then navigate to each article scrape the text content for each article.

I have tried by using rules and linkextractor but it's not able to navigate to next page and extract. i get the ERROR: Spider error processing https://blogs.webmd.com/diabetes/default.htm> (referer: None)

Below is my code

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor


class MedicalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'medical'
    allowed_domains = ['https://blogs.webmd.com/diabetes/default.htm']
    start_urls = ['https://blogs.webmd.com/diabetes/default.htm']

    Rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(), restrict_css=('.posts-list-post-content a ::attr(href)')), callback="parse", follow=True),)
    def parse(self, response):
        headline = response.css('.posts-list-post-content::text').extract()
        body = response.css('.posts-list-post-desc::text').extract()
        print("%s : %s" % (headline, body))

        next_page = response.css('.posts-list-post-content a ::attr(href)').extract()
        if next_page:
            next_href = next_page[0]
            next_page_url = next_href
            request = scrapy.Request(url=next_page_url)
            yield request
```

Please guide a newbie in scrapy to get this spider right for multiple articles on each page.

Answer (score 2):

Usually when using scrapy each response is parsed by *parse callback*. The main `parse` method is the callback for the initial response obtained for each of the `start_urls`.

The goal for that parse function should then be to "Identify article links", and issue requests for each of them. Those responses would then be parsed by another callback, say `parse_article` that would then extract all the contents from that particular article.

You don't even need that `LinkExtractor`. Consider:

```
import scrapy

class MedicalSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'medical'
    allowed_domains = ['blogs.webmd.com'] # Only the domain, not the URL
    start_urls = ['https://blogs.webmd.com/diabetes/default.htm']

    def parse(self, response):
        article_links = response.css('.posts-list-post-content a ::attr(href)')
        for link in article_links:
            url = link.get()
            if url:
                yield response.follow(url=url, callback=self.parse_article)

    def parse_article(self, response):
        headline = 'some-css-selector-to-get-the-headline-from-the-aticle-page'

        # The body is trickier, since it's spread through several tags on this particular site
        body = 'loop-over-some-selector-to-get-the-article-text'

        yield {
            'headline': headline,
            'body': body
        }
```

I've not pasted the full code because I believe you still want some excitement learning how to do this, but you can find what I came up with on this [gist](https://gist.github.com/phrfpeixoto/ba1fb520489fa6ffa8a7c0f29faf82f1)

Note that the `parse_article` method is returning dictionaries. These are using Scrapy's items pipelines. You can get a neat json output by running your code using: `scrapy runspider headlines/spiders/medical.py -o out.json`

Comment: For next page i am navigating with below code but i am getting null response for next page?
        url_apnd = "https://blogs.webmd.com/diabetes"
        next_page = response.css('.next a ::attr(href)').extract_first()
        print("Next Page %s :",next_page)
        print("URL " + response.urljoin(next_page))
        if next_page:
            yield scrapy.Request(response.urljoin(url_apnd,next_page),callback=self.parse)

Comment: Hi. I can't really understand that code. Please use code formatting for that.

Basically what you need to do for Crawling other pages is to `yield` another requests to the next page, right after that `for` loop on the `parse` method.

Comment: I have updated the gist, though I didn't really run it.

Comment: I was calling the next page method in wrong function. I corrected it.

Comment: Nice. If you got the help you wanted, please mark this as the correct answer to help other who end up here looking for the same answer.